# Assign SQL 'post_thumbnail' column as featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have added a column called `post_thumbnail` to my wp_posts table.

Is there any way I can make `post_thumbnail` to each post's featured image?

Comment: Why you had to add a custom column to the default posts table?

Comment: Because I am running a script that turns an RSS feed into WP posts and I don't know how else to transfer the RSS thumbnail as a featured image.

Comment: Take a look at this plugin [WP RSS Multi Importer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-multi-importer/)

Comment: There is more to my import script, that I need to keep. There should be a way to change where the featured image is found. Why is it basically impossible to find an answer to this anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the post_thumbnail information stored?

If you've already created an attachment with the image and are storing the attachment's `postId` in `post_thumbnail`, then you just need to go through your posts and update the meta using `update_post_meta($postId, '_thubmnail_id', $attachmentPostId)`.

If `post_thumbnail` stores the path to an image file on your server, you need to create an attachment using [wp_insert_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) and pass in that file location. If the files are not already stored in the uploads directory, you can use the [Add From Server plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) to import the files into wordpress as attachments. You can then use `update_post_meta` to set the attachment as your featured image.

If `post_thumbnail` stories the URI of the image, you need to [save it to your server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299798/wordpress-curl-save-images), then create the attachment, then update the post's meta.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. Does this mean that it is not possible to use images that are not stored in the wordpress blog? The post_thumbnail is just the url of an image on an external source.

Also, I'd like it to be automated, so I don't have to import anything continuously.

Comment: If you're trying to use Wordpress' Featured Image feature, the image needs to be stored by your blog. If you just want to display the image whenever the post is viewed, you can do modify the loop of the template that displays the post (ie. index.php, single.php, single-posttype.php depending on how much you've modified Wordpress) and put the url of the image inside of an <img> tag.

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about displaying the image to the relevant row? What code would I have to insert to post.php? I guess if I can do this there should be a plugin that transforms that image to the featured image?